# Gradle does not fill files with gradle.properties variables

Tags: java, gradle

At the moment my project just lacks some paths declared on gradle.properties which are:

```
M_HOME=/home/<USER>/Manager
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_191
```

And in build.gradle I have the task editing and moving a shell script to be introduced in the buildRpm task and compile the RPM package with the script located in `ProjectDir/src/main/resources/template`

My task for the script is the following:

```java
def mHome = project.findProperty('M_HOME')
def javaHome = project.findProperty('JAVA_HOME')

task createScript(type: Copy, dependsOn: build){

    description = "Create a setvar script"

    doLast{
        from 'src/main/resources/template'
        include 'setvar.sh.template'
        expand([
            M_HOME: 'mHome',
            JAVA_HOME: 'javaHome'
        ])
       // into 'out/scripts'
    }
}
```

And it puts the file into `ProjectDir/out/resources/main/template`

then in my build task for buildRpm is the following (not going to put all the code):

```
task buildRpm(type: Rpm, overwrite: true, dependsOn: build)
    if(mHome == '' )
        throw new GradleException('** Edit the value of your Manager Home in gradle.properties **')
    into(Home){
        addParentDirs = false
        fileMode 0644
        dirMode 0755

        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }")
        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }/lib")
        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }/config")
        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }/bin")
        directory("${Home}/${ packageName }/logs", 0777)
        from('out/resources/main/template/') {
            into "${ packageName }/bin"
            rename 'setvar.sh.template', "setvar.sh"
            fileMode 0755
        }
```

(packageName and Home are declared and funcional)
And It puts the script on `/opt/ToolDir/bin`

However, the script appears exactly the same as the template (without the .template extension) with both variables sitting there and unmodified

```
M_PATH=${M_HOME}
JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

The if statement containing mHome does throw the exception if the variable is null, so the build.gradle is reading the variables and my question is if gradle does replace variables in files with the variables declared on gradle.properties.

Or maybe it's my variables in the shell script badly declared